# binary search in the TreeMap

Tags: java, search, hashmap, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have two TreeMap

The first map is:

```
Map<String, Double> m1 = new TreeMap();
```

and the second is:

```
Map<String,double []> m2 = new TreeMap();
```

I want to search the Key in first map to the second one, and then multiply the value of the first map to the list of second map values (for the similar keys).

the code below works good for me, but when the `TreeMaps` are large the search takes more time, I want to increase the speed for that, how can I do a binary search for that.
Another question what's the fastest way to do the search is it the `TreeMap` or the `HashMap` ?

```
double[] finalSum = new double[N];

for ( Map.Entry<String,Double> entry : m1.entrySet() ) {
     if ( m2.containsKey(entry.getKey()) ) {
         //if the key is common in map1 and map2, compare the values
         double y=entry.getValue();
         double j[]=m2.get(entry.getKey());
         for (int u=0;u<j.length;u++){
             finalSum[u] += y * j[u];
         }}}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big-O notation of HashMap and TreeMap:

```
                     get      containsKey next     Notes
HashMap               O(1)     O(1)        O(h/n)   h is the table capacity
TreeMap               O(log n) O(log n)    O(log n) 
ConcurrentHashMap     O(1)     O(1)        O(h/n)   h is the table capacity
```

If the keys are already known on which you want to retrieve values for, from treemap. I would suggest to rather use HashMap as the Big-O of Hashmap is O(1) to get an element as compated to TreeMap which is O(log n).

> I want to search the Key in first map to the second one, and then
>   multiply the value of the first map to the list of second map values
>   (for the similar keys).

By using HashMap, you could retrieve the values from both the HashMaps using Keys and return the multiplication of first value with value from second hashMap.

Comment: In my case i will use the getKey , getValue and containsKey methods, so the big-o of them will be O(1), that's looks great, so do I need to write them using the binary search? and what is the Big-O of the method remove().

Comment: Hi vlaxmi, I have a question here,does the hashmap always better than the treemap, consider that the treemap order alphabetically ? or that doesn't increase the speed

Comment: we would decide which one to use (hashmap/treemap) depending on the use case. You can find more details here - http://javarevisited.blogspot.hk/2015/08/difference-between-HashMap-vs-TreeMap-vs-LinkedHashMap-Java.html